# Trying to deploy a cloud function to my firebase under an existing project. Help me fix or find the error?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

```
C:\Users\alpha\cmj_flutter_app>firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'cognitive-matters-journa-11c6a'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint C:\Users\alpha\functions
> eslint "src/**/*"

Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build

> functions@ build C:\Users\alpha\functions
> tsc

src/index.ts:1:1 - error TS6133: 'functions' is declared but its value is never read.
 

import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! functions@ build: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\alpha\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-20T04_21_16_357Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code2
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that there's a problem with your code.  Please read it carefully:

```
src/index.ts:1:1 - error TS6133: 'functions' is declared but its value is never read.
 

import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

You are declaring a variable called `functions` on the first line, but you never used it.

I can only imagine that you didn't edit and save the default file you were given when you initialized the project.

Comment: Doug, thank you for that comment i just spotted it and if i may ask how do i fix it that error?

Comment: Use the variable `functions` in some way in your code.  You can't deploy a function without it.

Comment: Hi again Doug, i am still struggling to fix the above error. i followed your suggestions but i was not successful in deploying it again. Please Help!

Comment: I just wrote this line: `const deleteME = functions.https;`  and still NO luck